# Randomize color of each div continuously

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

I'm trying to replicate what is seen in this gif:
[Grid Layout](https://gifyu.com/image/8jhA)

I have to randomize the colors of each div inside the grid-container every second using `setInterval()` and `querySelectorAll()` after clicking the button on the top left corner, and display the current time as seen in the GIF. I know that the colors are randomly selected and actually use the CSS rgba() function. Here's what I have in my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

</style>

<script>
var r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

function changeColor(){
  for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('div')) {
    r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    elem.style.backgroundColor =  "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+", 0.8)";
  }

  var myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
  var running = true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>This grid layout contains six columns and three rows:</p>

<div class="flex-container">
    <button onclick="changeColor()">GO!</button>
    <p id="timeinfo">TIME</p>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm lost in regards to that. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your javascript code please?

Comment: Done. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the setInterval() function out of the changeColor() function. You are creating a new interval with each subsequent changeColor() recursive call, and that is what's causing the speed up until we become epileptic. Plus add the more specific selector others have mentioned ('.grid-container > div'). This is something that is probably better done in a reactive style, rather than looping through an array of elements every second, but if you are just getting into html/js/css this is a pretty good little test. I would probably do something more like this:

```
var r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var myTimer;

function startSwitching() {
  myTimer = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
}

function stopSwitching() {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function changeColor(){
  for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('.grid-container > div')) {
    r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    elem.style.backgroundColor =  "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+", 0.8)";
  }
}
```

You need to be careful using intervals and make sure you clean up after yourself, or you could crash the browser. Also, you didn't really ask a question, so it's unclear what exactly you are wanting to change.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('div')` actually returns a list of elements. In order to change the styling, you'll want to iterate through the elements. Here's one way you could go about doing that:

```
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('.grid-container > div')) {
    r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}
```

Comment: I did that and the function works but all of the divs, include the grid-container itself changes its color. How can I specify to where only the divs inside the grid-container change their color?

Comment: Instead of saying `document.querySelectorAll('div')`, you could do something like `document.querySelectorAll('.grid-container > div')` so that the selector is **only selecting** the divs inside the grid-container.

This means that we're selecting all divs where .grid-container is a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Add `document.querySelectorAll('.grid-container > div')` in for loop, so that only divs inside `grid-container` will change color.